# Error getting JSON data in DataTable Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatables

I have a `DataTable` in my project and I'm trying to populate it with a collection of data being retrieved through Ajax call, but I'm getting an error during that

This is my `DataTable` definition code:

```
$("#example").DataTable({
            destroy: true,
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            "columnDefs": [{
                orderable: false,
                targets: 0
            }],
            ajax: {
                type: "POST",
                url: "OpenTicket.aspx/PopulateAllTokens",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log("Request: " + JSON.stringify(XMLHttpRequest) + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
                },
            },
            "columns": [
                {
                    "data": "slno",
                    "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                        $(nTd).html('<a href="AddNewTicket.aspx?subjectID=' + oData.subjectID + '&subject_id=' + oData.subject_id + '&serviceID=' + oData.service_id + '&severityID=' + oData.severityID + '&statusID=' + oData.statusID + '&callerID=' + '66355356' + '">' + oData.slno + '</a>');
                    },
                },
                { "data": "status_message" },
                { "data": "service_id" },
                { "data": "subject_id" },
                { "data": "severity_id" },
                { "data": "user_id" },
                { "data": "status_id" },
                {
                    "data": "caller_number",
                    "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                        console.log(oData.caller_number);
                        $(nTd).html('<button class="btn btn-primary" id= "' + oData.subjectID + '" name="' + oData.caller_number + '">Call Customer</button>');
                    },
                }
            ],
            select: {
                style: 'os',
                selector: 'td:first-child'
            },
            //"data": response,
            "sDom": '<"top">tip'
        });
```

If i use the same `AJAX` call outside the `DataTable` it works perfectly and it returns the data normally, but when I use it with the `DataTable` it gives me this error:

> jquery-1.12.4.js:10254 POST http://localhost:9057/OpenTicket.aspx/PopulateAllTokens 500 (Internal Server Error)
>
> Status: error
>
> Error: Internal Server Error

I assume that the response JSON format is not readable by the `DataTable`, if this is correct may anyone please suggest me how to fix it?

Comment: If it throws a server error it's most likely the JSON was never generated. Use Chrome Dev Tools network tab to inspect both cases (the one that works and the one that doesn't). Maybe Datatables formats the request differently, and the server doesn't get it.

Comment: A http 500 error means you have a severe error in `/PopulateAllTokens`, it could be anything from a typo in the code to a failed db connection - it has nothing to do with dataTables, clientside scripts cannot throw serverside errors.